# How to communicate with a process using Twisted?

Tags: python, asynchronous, ipc, twisted

The Twisted Documentation on Processes - https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html gives an example on how to start a process, send input, and then collect the output. 
My requirement is a process which requires active two-sided communication, i.e. The master process sends a line, then the child receives the line and sends it back after modifying it, the master sends a new line, and so on, continuously. 
It seems the lineRecieved callback would work for me, but the ProcessProtocol class only has an outReceived callback.

Is what I am trying possible with Twisted? If not, can you suggest any other method by which such a communication could be accomplished asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`ProcessEndpoint`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.ProcessEndpoint.html) with [`LineReceiver`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html).